# D3.js: Force-layout - Nodes not rendering with images

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Currently I am working one of [FCC' Project](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/show-national-contiguity-with-a-force-directed-graph) and
I am trying to have node render with images from these flag sprites (https://www.flag-sprites.com/)

However, my nodes are not rendering, yet I see in my dev tool that are there.

[Codepen - Not Working](http://codepen.io/neotriz/pen/wzpEjj?editors=1010)

```
const width = w - (margin.left + margin.right);
const height = h - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

let svg = d3.select("#canvas")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("id","chart")
              .attr("width", w)
              .attr("height", h)

let flagNodes = svg.append("div")
                  .classed("flag-nodes",true)
                  // .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let chart = svg.append("g")
                .classed("display", true)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d,i) {
      return i;
      }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-4))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2))

let node = flagNodes.append("div")
        .selectAll(".flag-nodes")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
          .append("div")
          .attr("class", function(d,i){
            return `flag flag-${d.code}`
          })
          .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended)
          )

let link = chart.append("g")
        .classed("links",true)
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(data.links)
        .enter()
          .append("line")


node.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return d.country; });

simulation
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

simulation.force("link")
    .links(data.links);

//functions provided by D3.js
//
function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y;});

    node
        .style("left", function(d) {
          // console.log(d)
          return d.x + 'px'
         })
        .style("top", function(d) {
          return d.y + 'px'
         });
  }

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

Comment: So, what part of the code do you expect to load the images?

Comment: from `attr("class", function(d,i){return `flag flag-${d.code}`})`  . I am using CSS's url to get the image

Comment: Then post the CSS ;)

Comment: check out the codepen link. CSS's file may be too long

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` elements are added to the HTML document and the links are added to `<svg>` element. They do not share the same coordinate system. Unfortunately you cannot add a `<div>` to an `<svg>`.  It is probably easier to use another method for the flags instead of trying to coordinate both systems. You could use separate images for each flag and use `<img>` inside the `<svg>`.